# LWJGL - Making the 3D FPS camera jump

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, game-physics

So I am working on my first 3D project and everything went well till I decided to make the FPS character (camera) jump. I tried some methods and all of them didn't look well till I succeeded to do something that works **most** of the time. Now the problem is the "most of the time" - Which should be **all** the time.

The problem is that when I click the jump button continuously it starts to freak out. I tried to set the position always back to zero when I exceed it but it still freaks out sometimes although less often. Any suggestions how to do it in order for it to work all the time? (I am working with OpenGL and java without an engine)

The jumping part code:

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE) && !jumping
    && position.y >= temp) { //temp - floor height 
jumping = true;
}
gravity = (float) ((walkingSpeed * 0.00003) * delta);//delta - time
//System.out.println(delta);
if (position.y < temp) { //In the air
    speed = speed + gravity;
    position.y = position.y + speed;
}
if (jumping) {
    speed = speed - (float) ((walkingSpeed * 0.0006) * delta);
    position.y = position.y + speed;
    jumping = false;
}
if (position.y > temp) //**Supposed** to solve the problem
    position.y = temp;
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what your problem is. Is the problem that you can jump while in mid-air? You should probably maintain the `jumping` state as **true** until you hit the ground, rather than immediately resetting it after applying an instantaneous change to speed. Doing that properly will of course require collision detection of some sort, but you could naively assume that the ground is a horizontal plane and test against initial height (which I think you are sort of doing right now).

Comment: By the way, some FPS games allow you to double-jump, so rather than making `jumping` a boolean you might consider using an integer counter.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - I have already blocked jumping in mid air and yes, I am looking right now at the floor as a horizontal plane. My problem is when I click constantly on the space bar. At first, it jumps regularly but after some time it starts to jump suddenly X10 from what I wrote or the opposite. I have no idea why it is happening and I need an advice how to do it better\ fix it. About double jump - not now. I need the basics to work first. I am working on simple walking in a regular room, later i will expand it.

Comment: Well, yes. The problem here is that if you hold the space bar down continuously it does not prevent you from jumping an infinite number of times. You should only set `jumping` to false after you hit the ground. Otherwise every frame that happens while spacebar is down is going to cause you to jump.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - No, that's not the problem of making me jump again.
I jump and fall down and only when I touch the floor I can jump again (look at the first if statement in the code). I will try to explain better. I am supposed to jump from y=0 to y=3 for example and it works. But sometimes it suddenly jump to y=17 when I click the space bar ONCE. That happens after I clicked the space bar continuously before (sometimes it jumps to y=0.5 too for example). Something happens there that makes it freak out even in regular jumps and I have to reopen the game for it to work again.

Comment: This is just flawed logic all around. `jumping` is never true when this if statement is evaluated (it is always reset to **false** at the end of this code) and `position.y` is set to `temp` at the end as well. Your condition for jumping is `>=` and a value `==` will satisfy that condition. The sign of `Y` seems to be backwards in every part of this code versus what you are describing.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - I can't seem to understand whats wrong yet.... Can you write the fixed code  for me?

Answer (score 0):

#### There are a number of issues in your code that don't synch up with what you are describing:

1. You have the sign reversed for virtually everything
2. You are testing for a condition that ***always*** evaluates to **true** (`!jumping`)

---

```
// Only start a jump while on the ground (position.y <= temp)
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE) && position.y <= temp) {
  speed = speed + (float) ((walkingSpeed * 0.0006));
  // Don't care about the delta time when you jump, just add a fixed amount of
  // positive vertical velocity (which gravity will work out over time).
}

// You had gravity going the wrong direction initially
gravity = (float) -((walkingSpeed * 0.00003) * delta);

//System.out.println(delta);
speed      = speed + gravity;
position.y = position.y + speed;

if (position.y < temp) { // Don't sink into the ground
  position.y = temp;
  speed      = 0.0; // Scrub off acceleration due to gravity
}
```

Comment: He probably has screen coordinates with 0 at the top of the screen, hence -y is up. Not really a problem, just counter intuitive.

Comment: @schmop: Actually, this was all in response to some lengthy comments where he refers to jumping from Y=0 to Y=3. That means that the direction in his head/discussion is different from that in code.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - Just saw it and tried.... I was wrong and it really was -y.... Anyway, I tried that code instead and the same problem occurs. I guess the problem is somewhere else? Should I give more of the code? I am really lost here.